# CSS3 animation is not working on Mozilla firefox

Tags: html, css, mozilla, css-animations

I am trying to make the flapping effect of bird using CSS3 `keyframes`. It is working fine on google chrome. It does not seem to work on mozilla firefox.

here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwaran/M2WeW/3/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works if you use `-moz-animation: fly 0.2s steps(4) 10;`. It looks like firefox is having some issues with the way you have shorthanded the animation properties.

I'm not sure what the other 0 was supposed to be for, but it doesn't look like it's needed unless I am missing something...

Edit: I verified in Chrome that the extra 0 isn't needed either:

```
.follow-button:hover {
    -webkit-animation: fly 0.2s steps(4) 10;
    -moz-animation: fly 0.2s steps(4) 10;
    animation: fly 0.2s steps(4) 10;
}
```