# Animation onclick thrice doesnt work in mozilla firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, animation

Animation works in following browser:

1) Internet explorer
2) chrome

Doesnt work in:
1) Mozilla firefox

```js
var $tab1 = $('.tab1');
$tab1.addClass('active');
$tab1.addClass('onloadStopAnimation');
setTimeout(function() {
console.log('came');
  $('.tab1').removeClass('onloadStopAnimation');
}, 5000);

$('.tab1').addClass('active');
var callTab = function(passon,passonTab) {
 $(passon).addClass('active');
  $(passonTab).removeClass('active');
}
```

```css
div {
  position: relative;
}
span {
  display: table-cell;
padding: 1rem;
font-size: 1.4rem;
font-weight: bold;
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: none;
color: #fff;
background: blue;
cursor: pointer;
text-align: center;
width: auto;
border: none;
vertical-align: bottom;
}

.onloadStopAnimation {
  animation-duration: 0s !important;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0s !important;
  -moz-animation-duration: 0s !important;
  -o-animation-duration: 0s !important;
  -ms-animation-duration: 0s !important;
}

.active {
  background-color: gray;
}

.active:after{
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 10px 9px 0 9px;
  border-color: blue transparent transparent transparent;
  bottom: -1rem;
  left: 5%;
  margin-left: -9px;
  animation: rightFrames ease 1s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -webkit-animation: rightFrames ease 1s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -moz-animation: rightFrames ease 1s;
  -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -moz-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -o-animation: rightFrames ease 1s;
  -o-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -o-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  -ms-animation: rightFrames ease 1s;
  -ms-animation-iteration-count: 1;
  -ms-transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}

@keyframes rightFrames{
  0% {
    transform:  translate(0px,0px) ;
  }
  100% {
    transform:  translate(200px,0px);
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes rightFrames{
  0% {
    -moz-transform:  translate(0px,0px);
  }
  100% {
    -moz-transform:  translate(200px,0px) ;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes rightFrames {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform:  translate(0px,0px);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform:  translate(200px,0px);
  }
}

@-o-keyframes animationFrames {
  0% {
    -o-transform:  translate(0px,0px);
  }
  100% {
    -o-transform:  translate(200px,0px);
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes rightFrames {
  0% {
    -ms-transform:  translate(0px,0px);
  }
  100% {
    -ms-transform:  translate(200px,0px);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span class="tab1" onclick="callTab('.tab1','.tab2')">
     Tab 1
    </span>
  <span class="tab2" onclick="callTab('.tab2','.tab1')">
     Tab 2
    </span>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle Link click here ==>>](https://jsfiddle.net/snehav27/2gxrtv1t/7/)

To reflect:

Click on the tab1 and tab2 and tab1

Can somebody throw a light on why it doesnt work in mozilaa firefox (I have added keyframes for mozilla support). Any insight on this will be appreciated.

Comment: Well it might be an issue possibly [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37942642/css-animation-doesnt-work-in-mozilla?rq=1).

Comment: do you mean duplicate post or duplicate css?

Comment: I mean the issue might be the same cause possibly with [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22922432/css3-animation-is-not-working-on-mozilla-firefox?rq=1) too. I saw a couple of more similar questions caused by `Mozilla`. I don't have the solution yet, maybe they give you some point.

Comment: I tried the above mentioned question before asking this question it didnt work.